# How could I query Firebase geo locations without GeoFire in order to return results based on distance between two points?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Firebase just updated their sdk to 3.x and the current version of GeoFire 2.x doesn't work.

What I would like to know is the best way to store geo location values so that I can query firebase so that we only return location with in a defined radius around the user.

Example: user defines that they would like all items that are within 20 miles or less from them.

I wonder if I could store a single value from the latitude and longitude that would allow me to quickly query for this data? Or maybe that isn't the right approach ?

Comment: That sounds like the precise use-case that GeoFire was made for. We're working on getting an update out there that works with the new SDKs. But we have a lot of libraries, so give us a few days or weeks.

Comment: I moved over to Firebase after removing Parse from my app. One of the main reasons I moved to Firebase was the ease of implementation and for GeoFire. My app relies heavily on searching distance. It is very disappointing that they update breaks the current GeoFire.

Comment: The current GeoFire continues to work on the API it was designed for: Firebase Database 2.x, which can be used on both legacy Firebase.com project and projects that have been upgrades to the new Firebase console.  Firebase APIs follow semantic versioning. We've increased the major version of these, to indicate that this release includes breaking changes. We're working to get a new GeoFire out that works with the 3.x SDKs. Note that GeoFire is an open-source project, so PRs are always welcome.

Comment: I actually have a similar use case and I would like to know the current status of GeoFire. Would it be possible to show an example replying the question of @mattwallace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using pure firebase without implementing some sort of geohash (it is what geofire does). You could use an externa index stored in elastic search or in redis for example